# Need to iterate over all the items in my current directory and print their names along with other operations

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, cat

I need to create a loop that will iterate over all the items in my current directory to check whether this item is file, then print the name of the file and the 1st 10 lines of the file.

I did the following:

```bash
for f in *;do if [ -f "$f" ];then echo "$f" | cat $f | head -n 10;fi;done >output.txt
```

this code extracts 10 lines from each file but does not print the file name first.

So, I need to save the output as printed filename first, followed by the first 10 lines from it.

Comment: There is also a simpler method that you can easily do without loop, check my solution too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by this code:

```bash
for f in *;do if [ -f "$f" ];then echo "$f"; cat $f | head -n 10 $f; echo "---------------";fi;done >hello.txt
```

Comment: The `cat $f |` is redundant.  (`head` is given a filename argument so it doesn't read standard input.)  Fails for filenames that start with hyphen (`-`).  Ignores filenames that start with dot (`.`).  Also fail for filenames that contain spaces and other special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Same as other answers, but saves a few keystrokes :

`for f in *;do [ -f "$f" ] && printf "%s\n" "$f" && head -10 "./$f"; done`

Here we replace the `if...then...fi` with `&&`.

Comment: Ignores filenames that start with dot, but the question doesn't mention such files so I guess it's up to the OP to decide if that's OK.  This is currently the only answer that handles all other valid filenames correctly (as far as I can tell).  Upvoted.

Comment: @pjh, thanks for pointing out the `-xxx` filenames issues. I initially simply copied another solution replacing only `if...then...else`, but without even checking for basic filenames issues.

Comment: Your experience is not unusual.  Almost all shell code that you will find on the internet, including on Stack Overflow, and in books etc., is broken.  The fact that this simple question received 6 broken answers illustrates the point very well.  It is *extremely* difficult to write, or find, reliable shell code.

Comment: @pjh it is easy actually, if you are not doing a lot of escaping.what stops you from specifying another IFS and stop complaining about spaces, which are not mentioned in question, btw?

Answer (score 0):

You can also done this by `find` command :

```
find . -type f | xargs -I % sh -c "printf 'Filename : %f\n'; head -n 10 %;"
```

in this case `.` means current directory and via `xargs` you can easily manage your output

good luck

Comment: This is vulnerable to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).  For instance, run it in a directory after creating a file with `echo test >'$(rm ~)'`.  (It will harmlessly try to run `rm` on your home directory.)  See [Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' \;)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#find_._-exec_sh_-c_.27echo_.7B.7D.27_.2BAFw.3B).  The code also fails with filenames that contains spaces, and other special characters.  In addition, it prints `./` before all filenames and the character `f` after all filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Do not pipe echo to cat, cat does not read stdin. Just print it.

```
for f in *; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f"
        head -n 10 "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `cat $f | head -n 10` should at least be `cat "$f" | head -n 10` or better `head -n 10 "$f"`

Comment: Fails for filenames that start with hyphen (`-`).  Ignores filenames that start with dot (`.`).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
for f in *;do if [ -f "$f" ];then echo "$f" && head -n 10 "$f";fi;done >> output.txt
```

you pipe echo result to cat. change pipe to `&&`.
also change `>` to `>>`, or else you'll have just the last line in `output.txt`.
and `cat`ing into `head` is redundant, since `head` can read files.
and check your script with filenames with spaces. maybe custom ifs is needed, or quotes.

Comment: Fails for filenames that start with hyphen (`-`).  Ignores filenames that start with dot (`.`).

Comment: out of scope of this question, i believe. anyway, using find instead of wildcard should solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution where the file name is printed by `head` itself:

```bash
head -10 $(for filename in *; do test -f "$filename" && echo "$filename"; done) > /tmp/out
```

Comment: Does not print the filename if there  is only one file.  Fails for filenames that contain spaces and other special characters.  (E.g. run it after creating a file with `touch 'a b'`.)  Fails if the directory contains a file called `-e`, `-E`, or `-n`.